# Notify icons on form load

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon

I've a number of forms in my C# application. I am using notifyIcon only on the very first form. The problem I am facing is that when I load other forms (at run-time) they also create notifyIcons in system tray.

Note: Only two forms are causing this problem.

Please tell me how can I avoid it.

Comment: Remove the code that creates the additional icons from your other forms obviously.

Comment: There is no such code related to notifyIcon on other forms.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your icon code - launch the other forms and see why it's happening.

Comment: Do the two forms causing the problem inherit from the form with the NotifyIcon?

Answer (score 0):

if you have 1 process with few form than use 1 instance of notifyIcon or count of them and do not show more 1 notifyIcon

if you have 2 or more process - you have problem =)

Comment: I think we cannot create multiple process copies except MPI and I am not working under MPI Environment.

Answer (score 0):

I set visible property to 'false' under 'property window' (for notifyIcon) and then set it to 'true' in form load event. The problem solved.